# XAMPP Virtual Host

Tags: php, apache, xampp, slim

I'm trying to use Slim to build a RestFUL API using PHP and to do so I have to enable and use Virtual Hosts. As soon as I enable the Virtual Host by uncommenting the Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf line in httd.conf of XAMPP my API works as expected but nothing else works! Even the out of the box dashboard of XAMPP can't be found anymore and when I go to localhost I get Page Not Found error.
I comment the Include and everything else works but my API doesn't work! 
I've tried to use .htaccess and adding other Virtual Hosts and so on but I can't get this to work!
Here is my Virtual Host file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/rewardsapi/api"
    ServerName rewardsapi
</VirtualHost>
```

My .htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

my .hosts files is:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   rewardsapi
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

How can I enable Virtual Host but at the same time get the system to work and serve other none virtual host folders under htdocs?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You could try this [Slim tutorial](https://gist.github.com/odan/d2b889c350aa2ea0ff8e5ca93ce588a2) for apache.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I wouldn't post here if I didn't read and followed that. I'll go and read again.

Comment: When it comes to VirtualHosts, only the first one it finds, for a port is taken, unless you use different `ServerName` values.  So if the default `VirtualHost *:80` for XAMPP does not specify a `ServerName` different from `rewardsapi`, only the first one found from top to bottom will be used.  Please post all `VirtualHost` sections you have (both the XAMMP and yours) in the question.

Comment: That's all I have, so so I need to define a VirtualHost for every single folder I have in htdocs?

Comment: I think you'll need a VirtualHost for localhost at least, if you want that dashboard back